# Celery losing connection and running the task again

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alQCy.png)

Task gets successfully completed but then celery looses connection and that task starts again.

This is settings.py file

[Settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtTNj.png)

I tried changing config settings but nothing worked

Comment: Please post the code and  error as text, not an image.